# Refreshing a parent route's model when creating new record in a child route?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a parent route that lists a number of objects and a child route that allows users to create new objects in a modal dialog. Something like:

```
// Parent route (app.colours)
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
        return this.store.findAll('colour');
    },
}
```

and a child route that allows you to add new objects:

```
// Child route (app.colours.create)
export default Route.extend({
    model() {
        return this.store.createRecord('colour');
    },
    actions: {
        save(colour) {
            color.save().then(() => this.transitionTo('app.colours'));
        }
    }
```

I notice that when I successfully create a new `colour` record and transition back to the parent route, the new record isn't in the list as the parent route's model hasn't been refreshed.

How can I tell the parent route to refresh its model from the child route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actions to the rescue. I got it working by sending the parent an action:

```
// Parent route (app.colours)
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
        return this.store.findAll('colour');
    },
    actions: {
        refreshModel() {
            this.refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
// Child route (app.colours.create)
export default Route.extend({
    model() {
        return this.store.createRecord('colour');
    },
    actions: {
        save(colour) {
            color
                .save()
                .then(() => {
                    this.send('refreshModel');
                    this.transitionTo('app.colours'));
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: findAll returns live record array, so that parent route model should be automatically updated.

Comment: Because it's a parent route, I'm not sure the `beforeModel`, `model` and `afterModel` hooks are getting re-run when I transition to it so the record array will never be updated.